# Multiple File Selection and Upload In IE (version < 9)

Tags: php, javascript, html, file-upload

The code am using to select multiple file(s) at a time and to upload them to server is :-

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm">
    <label for="myfile" style="cursor:pointer;">Click To Upload Photo(s)</label>:<input type="file" id="myfile" name="upload" multiple="multiple" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work in IE(version<9.0). Does Any one know how to select multiple files at a time in IE ? I have also tried BlueImp & valums File uploader for the same.

Comment: I would go for a flex/flash solution in browsers < IE9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve that with pure HTML in older browsers. I recommend using [Uploadify](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://www.uploadify.com/&ei=E4EKUbSJDPOX0QWSsoCwAw&usg=AFQjCNEpTOmRIaTRQ7F8JNaxa7VhKljjwQ) as a combination of jQuery + Flash solution.

You can read about `multiple` attribute for an input [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-multiple). In my opinion it's still in early stages

Comment: This is not working for in IE9 .Are you sure this flash solution works ?